# React router not recognizing a new :flag with history.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route:

```
<PrivateRoute path={'/single-course/:courseId/v/:videoId'} exact  component={StudentVideoContainer}/>
```

where the `:videoId` is the id of a certain object in the db. When the `StudentVideoContainer` loads it will fetch the video embed url from the db and play it inside a playlist. When the video finishes I want to go to the next video in the playlist. However when I use

```
    if (this.state.nextVideo){
            this.props.history.push(`/single-course/${this.props.course.id}/v/${this.state.nextVideo.id}`);
        }
```

the url updates from say `/single-course/351/v/999` to `/single-course/351/v/1000` but the component doesn't reload. So I tried just navigating to another page, one which is just `/single-course/351` and this does work. What I think is happening is the router isn't recognizing that I've changes pages because the urls are the same between videos, expect for the `:videoId` flag. Anyone have an answer to how to fix this?

Comment: Can you `console.log` something in `componentDidUpdate` to see if new props are actually being received?
The `videoId` props should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component does not reload, becuase the route resolves to the same component - so the component does dot unmount.

You have to add some mechanism, that will track the change of the route param in `StudentVideoContainer` component - I bet that You fetch the videos just after first render ( like `componentDidMount` ), but You have to also do some logic on `componentDidUpdate`.